# What are the /proc/drivers directories organisation for nouveau or radeon

Tags: linux, nvidia, proc, radeon, nouveau

The context:

I need to get some basic informations from the graphic card in a lib in lua. The idea is to not rely on external software (like hwinfo for example).

I know that for a system with an nvidia card there is a nvidia directory in /proc/driver :

```
~/ tree /proc/driver/nvidia 
/proc/driver/nvidia
├── gpus
│   └── 0000:01:00.0
│       ├── information
│       └── registry
├── params
├── patches
│   └── README
├── registry
├── version
└── warnings
    └── README

4 directories, 7 files
```

I can get graphic cards informations from file nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0. In order to allow my lib to get informations on most platforms (with a graphical server), I would like to know :

1) Does nouveau and radeon provide such directories in /proc/driver

2) If yes, how are they named/organized?